# Can't free up space on SSD

Tags: windows-xp, ssd

I've got this strange problem where deleting files from C drive (e.g. uninstalling programs, clearing temp dir etc.) does not make the available space any bigger. If fact every time I uninstall a program the disk space is reduced a little.
I am physically deleting files - they are not in recycle bin.

The laptop is a HP Mini 1004TU and it's got an 8GB SSD and Windows XP Home edition.

A ran a program called Scanner to check what the disk space is used by, and it's showing 2GB free, but when I open drive properties it shows only 360MG free.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Ran `CHKDSK /F` and had to restart the system to proceed with the scan. Nothing special noted during scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to wear leveling, and the way used flash memory blocks [must be erased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Block_erasure). The space may be made available when the disk gets more full, but if it is almost full then a block of flash cannot be erased if some part of a used file is on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CHKDSK /F` and tell us the results. Often these are due to filesystem problem. Note that CHKDSK does modify the disk and if you have problem with that better backup the system first.

In other cases the SSD may be to the end of its life (Judging from the size). Good luck.